# Calling a javascript function on button onclick

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick

I want to call a function `Encode` when a button is clicked.

My code is:

```
let data = document.getElementById("d1");
let encode = document.getElementById("btnEncode");
let encrypt = document.getElementById("btnEncrypt");
let display = document.getElementById("i1");
let form = document.getElementById("form1");

function Encode() {
  let l = data.value;
  console.log(l);
  l = btoa(l);
  display.value = l;
  console.log(l);
}
```

When I use `encode.onclick=Encode();` the value of `l` is empty in `Encode()` and when I use `encode.addEventListener("click", Encode);`, it works fine.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: `Encode()` will fire the code. Consider using `onclick = Encode;` instead? --- Also, you mention the value of `i`, but the example doesn't use `i` anywhere.

Comment: @evolutionxbox — That's `l` not `i`

Comment: That's why you don't use `i` or `l` as a variable!

Comment: @Quentin I'm going to book an eye test now

Comment: This is why Stack uses a font with serifs on the l for code :)

Comment: @Quentin the early edit of the question didn't use a serif font. 

Comment: @evolutionxbox That was my point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encode.onclick()` tries to call `onclick` **immediately**. This gives you a *value*. (Or it throws an exception because it is `undefined` instead of a function you can call).

`=Encode();` then calls `Encode` **immediately** and tries to assign its return value to the LHS. Since the LFS is a value (and not a property or a variable), this throws an error.

The correct (albeit ancient) syntax would be `encode.onclick = Encode`.

The modern approach is `addEventListener`. Stick to that.